# Select active state of state history table in a given period

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jpa

I have a simple table containing a history of states of a 'reader' object. The state can be ACTIVE or INACTIVE. Now I would like to have a query, which picks all readers, which were ACTIVE in a given period. The following image shows what I mean: The 'readers' with the green 'lifeline' were ACTIVE in the displayed period; so they shall be returned in the query.

[image]

The tabel `ReaderActivity` looks like this (example only, not matching image above):

```
reader_id | state    | timestamp
 1        | ACTIVE   | 1467331201089
 2        | ACTIVE   | 1467332454545
 1        | INACTIVE | 1467348875254
 3        | ACTIVE   | 1467350416546
 1        | ACTIVE   | 1467351871123
 2        | INACTIVE | 1467352111545
```

Of course, there is a `Reader` Entity to which this `reader_id` is mapped to.

I need to have a JPA query for this, but I have problems including the readers into the result, which have no 'rising edge' (state change from INACTIVE to ACTIVE) within the period (which were already active before the period we look into).

I see basically too parts of the query:

- First, select all having a rising edge. This is simple: `SELECT DISTINCT a.reader FROM ReaderActivity a WHERE a.timestamp >= :startTimestamp AND a.timestamp < :endTimestamp AND a.state = 'ACTIVE'`
- Secondly, it should append to the list above all readers, which has as last state ACTIVE before start of period. This is what I do not get correctly: I tried (combined into the fist query): `SELECT DISTINCT a.reader FROM ReaderActivity a WHERE a.timestamp >= :startTimestamp AND a.timestamp < :endTimestamp AND a.state = 'ACTIVE' or (SELECT aa.reader FROM ReaderActivity aa where aa.reader = a.reader AND aa.timestamp < :startTimestamp AND aa.state = 'ACTIVE' GROUP BY aa.reader ORDER BY max(aa.timestamp)) != null`

This returns also the red marked reader in the image above because with the `AND aa.state = 'ACTIVE'` in the sub query, we already filter out all ACTIVE state so the last one is of course ACTIVE. I should select the last state before start period and afterwards check, if it is ACTIVE or not. But how?

Can anybody bring me to the right way?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your query will bring back records whose state changed to active during the time period as you wanted.  The second part of the query needs some refining.

To do what you are asking, you are going to have to bring back the most recent state changes for every reader_id up until the moment of "startTimeStamp". From these, you will then simply select the ones that were listed as "ACTIVE" at that time.

Something like..

```
Select a.reader_id 
From ReaderActivity a 
Where a.timeStamp in
( 
  Select max(b.timeStamp) 
  From ReaderActivity b 
  Where b.timestamp < :startTimeStamp 
  And b.reader_id = a.reader_id 
  Group By b.reader_id
)
and a.state = "ACTIVE"
```

This query will return all [reader_id]'s that were active at the start of the specified time period.  You can run this inside your original query's where clause or you can just append it to the end of your query with a UNION and run a Select Distinct(reader_id) on that whole mess.

Selecting from the max value of a group in a table is always kind of quirky to me.  But I hope this query helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, Luke! I missed the possibility to use `...where in () ... ` [+1] - My full query is now: `SELECT DISTINCT a.reader FROM ReaderActivity a WHERE a.timestamp >= :startTs AND a.timestamp < :endTs AND a.state = 'ACTIVE' OR (a.timestamp IN (SELECT MAX(b.timestamp) FROM ReaderActivity b WHERE b.timestamp < :startTs GROUP BY b.reader) AND a.state = 'ACTIVE')` - One question: Why did you enclosed `state` in square brackets in the final and (`... and a.[state] = ...`)?

Comment: Can't we address your important hint *The only thing to watch out for with this query is that if for some reason a reader_id 'a' was set to "INACTIVE" at the exact millisecond...* by adding ... `where b.reader_id = a.reader_id` in the sub select's where clause?

Comment: In response to your first question, removing the brackets from state will not alter the query, and neither will having them there.  Brackets are needed around a column to keep one column grouped together when the column consists of space separated words. For some reason I read state as two words (not sure how).  In response to your second question, yes!  Adding the where filter on a.reader_id = b.reader_id will prevent bringing back an 'INACTIVE' record. I'll alter the query to reflect this.  @badera

Answer (score 1):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT r.reader_id, r.timestamp
FROM ReaderActivity r 
WHERE   r.timestamp>=:start AND 
        r.timestamp<=:stop AND 
        r.state='ACTIVE' 

UNION ALL 

SELECT r1.reader_id, r1.timestamp
FROM ReaderActivity r1 
LEFT JOIN ReaderActivity r2 ON (r2.reader_id = r1.reader_id AND 
                                r2.timestamp<:start AND 
                                r2.timestamp>r1.timestamp)
WHERE   r1.timestamp<:start AND 
        r1.state='ACTIVE' AND 
        r2.id IS NULL
```

The fisrt part of the UNION selects the readers that activated within the time period and the second part of the UNION selects only readers that activated before the time period.

I didn't tested the query, you may need to adjust a little.

Comment: Thank you too, Victorqedu! [+1] Sorry that I did not mark your answer as 'accepted'; but the one from Luke is a little bit bether.

Comment: Selecting by timestamp is not safe - as Luke mentioned in the end of his answer.

Comment: Why not, if the filter of the subquery is limited to the entry of the parent select? It is technically impossible, that two *readers* produce multiple entries with same timestamp. I think it would be bether to discuss this directly on the corresponding answer!

Comment: You are right but this is not the only problem. As far as I know joining a subquery is not as efficient as a table join and IN is not as efficient as =. I may be wrong  but I can't see what is better in the other solution.

Comment: For me, the other query is more transparent and handy. To be honest, I do not fully understand, what you do. Thats why I feel that the other answer is bether (yes, it is due to lack of knowledge...) You may change that, if you put some explanation, what you do :) - As far as the speed / resource usage is concerned, you may be right - if I once have large datasets, I could observe it.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN r2 matches only reader activities between r1.timestamp and :start. In the WHERE clause r2 is "asked" to be NULL and r1.state=ACTIVE. So the result will contain only last reader activies that are active before :start. Is important to understand  this kind of queries because they are very efficient.

Comment: Thank you @Victorqedu. It is clearer now. I will try your query.